# Python file searching trouble

Tags: python, file, search

I’m new to programming and could do with a little help.  I’m trying to make a program that will search for files in a specified directory by extension (multiple extensions) and then only return specific results which have my list of keywords in the filename.
I have the following:

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch

root = 'c:\users'
pattern = "*.css"

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        if fnmatch(name, pattern):
            print os.path.join(name)
```

This will bring back all files with a single extension, in this case .css files, but I need it to do more such as image and text file extensions.  I would also like it to only return files that have specific keywords in the file name.  Can anyone point me in the right direction??
Thanks

Comment: So you need multiple extensions + keywords in your search ? Could you be just a bit more precise in what you are trying to search ?

Comment: For advanced pattern searching in the filename, you could also use regular expression (module `re`) matching too.

Comment: i'd ideally like to search for all image files in a specified location but only show results of files which have file names matching a keyword list... for example i have txt files one.txt two.txt three.txt, and my keywords are one and three, it will only return one.txt and three.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if you are searching for filetype and keywords, here would be some easy code to start with:

```
import os
import re

root = 'c:\users'
pattern = re.compile("((keyword1)|(keyword2))\.((txt)|(jpg))")

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        if re.match(pattern, name):
            print os.path.join(name)
```

This code will match the file extension `txt` or `jpg` and search for the keywords `keyword1` and `keyword2`.

If you want to make a more user-friendly code, to easily add extensions or keywords, you could use lists like so:

```
import os
import re

# configuration information 
root = 'C:\Users'
keywords = [ 'one', 'two']
extensions = [ 'jpg', 'txt' ]
use_wildcard = True # Enables you to catch the keyword anywhere in the filename
# end of configuration 

keyword_pattern = ''
first = True
for k in keywords:
    if use_wildcard:
        k = '.*' + k + '.*'
    if first:
        keyword_pattern += '(' + k + ')'
        first = False
    else:
        keyword_pattern += '|(' + k + ')'

extension_pattern = ''
first = True
for ext in extensions:
    if first:
        extension_pattern += '(' + ext + ')'
        first = False
    else:
        extension_pattern += '|(' + ext + ')'

pattern_regex = r"({0})\.({1})".format(keyword_pattern, extension_pattern)
print "Searching for: " + pattern_regex
pattern = re.compile(pattern_regex)

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        if re.match(pattern, name):
            print os.path.join(path, name)
```

I'm using regular expressions because they are very powerful and are useful in a lot of cases. They may seem complex at first sight but once you understand them, it's difficult not to use them :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer it's much appreciated, just a quick one if I'm searching about 20 different file extensions with the same amount of keywords would it be better to use lists or just input into the above?

Comment: Just add to the `extension` list (it's already a list) after `txt` and `jpg` or remove them and put in whatever you need.

Comment: I am of course referring to the `extensions` list defined in the `#configuration information` section of the python script posted above.

Comment: This code is super quick I can't thank you enough it's gonna be really handy for me at work

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use `glob`:

```
from glob import glob

for filename in glob('*.css'):
    print(filename)
```

If you have multiple extensions you can add the list returned by `glob()`:

```
exts = ['ccs', 'txt']

all = []
for ext in exts:
    all += glob('*.' + ext)

for filename in all:
    print(filename)
```